# Python: index 5324 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5040

Tags: python, índices, numpy

Olá, pessoal,

Tenho um código em Python que lê os 5040 números de um arquivo TXT para realizar uma simulação, conforme mostra a **Figura 1**. Em seguida, o código cria uma função B(s), que é usada nos comandos da **Figura 2** (pulei uma parte do código entre a Figura 1 e a Figura 2). No entanto, quando clico em `Run module`, o Python Shell mostra a mensagem de erro `IndexError: index 5324 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5040`, que é melhor vista na **Figura 3**.

Sou iniciante com o Python e embora já tenha encontrado erros similares com o Index do Numpy, nenhuma solução funcionou para o meu código.

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigado desde já,
Marcos Miotti

Figura 1 - Leitura do arquivo TXT e função B(s).
[image: Figura 1]

Figura 2 - Uso da função B(s).
[image: Figura 2]

Figura 3 - Mensagem de erro no Python Shell.
[image: Figura 3]

Comment: ve se tirando seu arquivo do dropbox funciona

Comment: Não, o mesmo erro aparece.

Comment: Já consegui resolver o problema.

Comment: Oi @MarcosPauloMiotti ! Eu estava editando a resposta e não percebi que você já havia solucionado o problema :-)

Comment: Marcos, evite colar código, listagens e erros como imagens: imagens não são texto, e só sção legíveis por pessoas com visão normal. Se você cola texto, pessoas com necessidades especiais podem ter o mesmo lido como áudio, o stackoverflow e o google vão poder indexar o seu problema por palavras chace no seu código, e todos- incluive usuários com visão normal, vão poder copiar trechos do seu código para um prompt de Python ou um editor de textos, para reproduzir seu problema e assim conseguir soluciona-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema: o programa tenta procurar no arquivo TXT um valor na 5324ª posição, mas há apenas 5040 números. Assim, reduzi o valor o valor do `s`um pouco. No primeiro código acima, escrevi

```
while s <= 0.524 and v >= 0.0:     # MOT position in the magnetic field files
```

Então, eu só mudei para

```
while s <= 0.50 and v >= 0.0:     # MOT position in the magnetic field files
```

Para os fins do meu código, essa solução funcionou bem. **:)**

Answer (score 0):

Como a variável de espaço `s` pode atingir um valor máximo de 0.524 no looping:

```
while s <= 0.524 and v >= 0
```

Dentro da função `B(s)` (que calcula o campo magnético em função do espaço), essa variável de espaço é multiplicada pela constante `1e4`, portanto o valor máximo que ela pode assumir dentro dessa função é **5240** (0.524*10000).

Porém, o array `Bfield` só possui 5040 elementos, que foram lidos a partir do arquivo.

O erro informado `IndexError` (índice do array fora do limite) indica que o algoritmo está tentando acessar o elemento 5234 de um array de 5040 elementos, portanto, em algum momento, o valor do espaço `s` deve estar assumindo um valor de 0.5234.

As possibilidades para solução do problema são: ou restringir o valor do espaço no looping `while` para um valor menor que **0.504**, ou verificar a possibilidade de acrescentar mais valores ao arquivo que contém os dados de campo magnético para atender todas as possibilidades de variação do espaço em `s`.

Mas para aplicar uma dessas soluções, é necessário verificar antes se elas atendem a necessidade do seu programa.